# Checking if an object exists and do something

Tags: angularfire2

There must be something I don't get right with angularfire2 5.0.

I want to check if an object exists in RTDB (my plan is if the object that the customer is querying doesn't exist, then I route to a different page).

```
    user.snapshotChanges().subscribe(obj => {
        console.log(obj.key);
        if(obj.key == null){
            result = false;
        }else{
            result = true;
        }
    });
```

Above is what I do but obviously, since the data is retrieved async, I always return false.
Before upgrading to 5.0 I would use exists() and preserveSnapshot but it doesn't seem to be an option anymore.